# Problema ao deletar da lista com recursão

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando usar essa função para remover da lista, mas ela executa infinitamente.

```
void rDeleta(lista* l, int elemento) {
    if(l!= NULL) {
        if(l->elem == elemento) {
            lista* aux = l;
            l = l->prox;
            free(aux);
        } else {
            rDeleta(l->prox, elemento);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como a sua função está rodando infinitamente. A impressão que eu tenho é que se essa função ficar presa num loop infinito ela deveria parar alguma ora com um erro de stackoverflow.

De qualquer forma, dá pra perceber algumas coisas erradas na sua implementação.

Vamos olhar a parte em que você está deletando o elemento. Assuma que temos uma lista A->B->C e você está tentando remover o B. Atualmente você está fazendo isso com um `l = l->prox`:

```
antes:

       l ---\
            |
            v
[ A ] --> [ B ] --> [ C ]

depois de  l = l->prox:

                l ---\
                     |
                     v
[ A ] --> [ B ] --> [ C ]
```

No entanto, a variável `l` é uma variável local da função rDeleta e em nenhum momento você alterou o valor o campo `prox` do nó "A" da lista.

A maneira mais simples de resolver esse problema é modificar a função `rDeleta` para ao invés de retornar void, retornar o ponteiro para a cabeça da lista que é obtida ao remover o elemento `elemento` da lista `l`.

Acho que com essa dica talvez você consiga resolver o seu exercício.

Comment: auterei anteriormente para tipo de retorno lista e funcinou.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente só faz a chamada do método dentro dele mesmo quando se trabalha com *Grafos*.

Como você está usando uma lista, basta apenas passar para o próximo elemento.

```
lista *rem;
while(l){
    rem = l;
    l = l->prox;

    free(rem)
}
```

Esse trecho limpa a lista inteira.

---

```
lista *rem;
lista *prev = l;
while(l){
    if(elemento == l->elem){
        rem = l;
        l = l->prox;
        prev->prox = l;
        free(rem);
        break; // encerra o loop
    }else{
        prev = l;
        l = l->prox;
    }
}
```

Esse trecho remove um item da lista

Comment: Ainda esta em loop infinito.

Comment: você está usando uma lista circular? o seu problema pode não ser na exclusão, mas sim em alguma parte da implementação. Pode ser que tenha algum endereço de memória errado que faz com que a lista fique em loop.

Comment: Criei um novo código, devia ser problema de memória.